# Getting buddy class information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, metadata, data-annotations, buddy-class

I'm trying to read buddy class metadata information for usage outside of the normal asp.net mvc 2 validation process.  I thought it would be as simple as saying:

```
DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();

var metaData = metadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(() => new T(), typeof (T));
```

That works, but is returning me the entire types metadata information and not just what is in the buddy information.  According to the MVC2 source ( It uses the buddy class support from  DataAnnotations, ) it should support getting the buddy data information but I don't see the part in the code where it reflects into the Metadatatype() attribute.

Generally confused here.  Did I miss an overload or something?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I have looked at literally 30 maybe 40 tutorials about why this Entity Framework "Database First" partial classes wasn't working. Then I found this post -- [MVC 4 EF5 Database First set Default Values in Partial Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616791/mvc-4-ef5-database-first-set-default-values-in-partial-class) -- that gave the following suggestion:

> [MetadataType(typeof(CompanyMD))]
>
> belongs in the partial class generated by the EF, even though it will
>   be erased if and when you change the model. So your EF-generated file
>   should look like this: