# Data Annotations not showing for partial Entity classes in MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have seen dozens of explanations of how to add metadata annotations, via partial classes, to classes generated via Entity Framework, **database first**.

Can someone tell me why these new display values are not showing in my views?  Both of these are part of the same namespace as my entity framework generated classes.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(xRef_CodesMetadata))]
        public partial class xRef_Codes
        {
        }

public class xRef_CodesMetadata
    {
        public int CodeID { get; set; }
        public int CTB_ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type a name")]
        [Display(Name = "Code Name")]
        [Column(TypeName = "Code Name")]
        public string CodeName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type a Description")]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [Column(TypeName = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }     
    }
```

Fragment of View:

```
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OfCodeID)
</th>
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodeName)
</th>
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
</th>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been resolved! I have looked at literally 30 maybe 40 tutorials about why this Entity Framework "Database First" partial classes wasn't working.  Then I found this post that gave the following suggestion:

> Sorry this is so late, but I just solved a similar scenario myself. I
>   believe the line
>
> [MetadataType(typeof(CompanyMD))]
>
> belongs in the partial class generated by the EF, even though it will
>   be erased if and when you change the model. So your EF-generated file
>   should look like this:

To see the rest of the post go this link...
[MVC 4 EF5 Database First set Default Values in Partial Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616791/mvc-4-ef5-database-first-set-default-values-in-partial-class)

Comment: This certainly worked for me, although it defeats the point a bit, as you're changing the EF-generated code.  Still clinging on to my database-first approach, but it's getting harder!

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help someone else but after following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation).

I also had the similar problem of my metadata not reflecting in my view.  The solution for me was having my metadata classes in the same namespace as my .edmx file, this line was the key "..., and each matches the name and namespace as the class that is automatically generated."

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare `xRef_CodesMetadata` class also as `partial` is as below.

```
public partial class xRef_CodesMetadata
        {
            public int CodeID { get; set; }
            public int CTB_ID { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type a name")]
            [Display(Name = "Code Name")]
            [Column(TypeName = "Code Name")]
            public string CodeName { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type a Description")]
            [Display(Name = "Description")]
            [Column(TypeName = "Description")]
            public string Description { get; set; }     
        }
```

May be useful for you [**Generating EF Code First model classes from an existing database**](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/24/generating-ef-code-first-model-classes-from-an-existing-database.aspx) and [**Adding Annotations for Data and Model-First Entities**](http://www.oakwoodinsights.com/adding-annotations-data-model-first-entities/)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: That didn't cause it to work.  I have also tried replacing all the var types with "object", per another forum, and that didn't help either.

Comment: @JonMorrissette Do you having N-tier app or just simple MVC project (all are in 1 project) ? You can try " [DisplayName("Code Name")]" like that also.check that.

Comment: @JonMorrissette I have updated some useful links.May be help for you.check that.

Comment: Sampath, you have been so gracious.  In the first link you provide they modify the entity framework *.tt file.  That works but then I cannot autogenerate new EF model without erasing my changes.

Comment: There has to be another explanation why these two partial classes are not working together.  Per second link I tried this approach too:  namespace CTB.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(CTB.Models.xRef_Codes))]
    public partial class xRef_Codes
    {        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a category")]
        [Display(Name = "Category")]            
        public int OfCodeID { get; set; }